# Keras accuracy with a custom loss function

Tags: keras, loss-function

I'm using a custom loss function in `Keras`:

```
def get_top_one_probability(vector):
  return (K.exp(vector) / K.sum(K.exp(vector)))

def listnet_loss(real_labels, predicted_labels):
  return -K.sum(get_top_one_probability(real_labels) * tf.math.log(get_top_one_probability(predicted_labels)))
```

How is computed the metric `accuracy` with a custom loss function?

Comment: loss and accuracy are two different things. Changing the loss function won't change the accuracy function. What are you trying to do? Is it binary classification or multiclass classififcation

Comment: @DvirSamuel I know that loss and accuracy are different. Maybe I formulate the question in a bad way. I would like to know if the accuracy computed by Keras is reliable also if I use a custom loss function.

Comment: It should be reliable. I know there is a trick when using custom loss function on binary classification tasks (so tell me if this is your case). But for other tasks, changing the loss function won't change the accuracy function.

Comment: @DvirSamuel my task is more like a regression problem. Basically I'm trying to order words in a sentence and to do this, my NN outputs a real number for each word and then ranking is applied to this outputs.

Comment: See my answer. I gave general answer for other people who will see this question

Answer (score 2):

Loss functions and accuracy functions are two different metrics.
Changing one won't change the other.  So if your task is a regression problem the accuracy function won't change and it will be fine (Keras use `regression accuracy` function for regression problem). Same for multiclass classification (Keras use `categorical_accuracy` function for the multiclass problem).

But, make sure that when the task is binary classification, changing the loss function changes your accuracy function from `binary_accuracy` to `categorical_accuracy` and thus you might end up with different results.
The solution for this is to use binary_accuarcy as follows:

```
def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)
model.compile(loss=custom_loss,
              metrics=[binary_accuracy])
```